# Opening a link after clicking a button from a modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, modal-dialog

I have a link, like this one:

```
<li class=""> <a class="alert_win" href="http://www.newtab.com/page/"> <span>Click me</span></a> </li>
```

To open the page in another tab, there will be a confirmation buttons a.k.a ("Yes" and "No"). Now, instead of confirming to open the page using an alert window, I have a customized modal that's perfectly designed. Could somebody help me how to display a modal with confirmation to open the page instead of an alert window? Can I do this using JQuery or javasript? Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: Where is this "perfectly designed modal"? Please check https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and update your question

Comment: @Chris Hi. The modal is composed of only yes or no buttons and a couple of texts above it.  Just like a bootstrap dialog.

Comment: You could make the `Yes` button a link to that page and add `target="_blank"`

Comment: Dunno about it but anymore ideas?

Comment: There are enough guides on how to display and subsequently hide a modal, whether the navigation is done via a link or js is up to you

Answer (score 0):

You can build a modal that pops up when you want to go to a specific page, then you put the link you want to go in the yes button on the modal with `target="__blank"` to make it open in another tab and when this button is clicked hide the modal .. I built an example in codepen to explain this [here](https://codepen.io/majidzeno/pen/qyVZze)

I hope that could help you

Comment: Too close! Thank you. But I need the link attached to the button at the first place, not in the modal.  Because I'm planning to add more than one links. That way, I only need to create one modal, instead of one modal for every each link. Get it? But this one really helps also. Thanks.